# Using sscanf to extract integers embedded in parenthesis

Tags: c, string, int, character, scanf

I want to extract from a string in c using sscanf. I have a have a sting that will always have the form `(int)string` i.e. `(10)foo`. I have tried this approach with no luck:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char buf[128] = "(10)foo",
         reg[4]; 
    int a;
    sscanf(buf, "([^'(']%[^')']) %s",a, reg);
    printf("a value = %d\nReg value = %s\n", a, reg);
}
```

output:

```
a value = 0
Reg value =
```

Comment: Did you forget a `%d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format specifier is wrong. You should turn the warning level higher to get useful feedback from your compiler. When I compile your program using `gcc -Wall`, I get:

```
soc.c: In function ‘main’:
soc.c:7:4: warning: format ‘%[^')'’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
    sscanf(buf, "([^'(']%[^')']) %s",a, reg);
    ^
soc.c:7:10: warning: ‘a’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
    sscanf(buf, "([^'(']%[^')']) %s",a, reg);
```

I am not sure what you expected that format string to do but it's not going to do what you want it to. You can use a much simpler format.

Other points:

Passing `a` to `scanf` family of functions will not work. You will need to pass `&a`.

Always check the return value of `scanf` family of functions to make sure that input was successful.

Here's an improved version of `main` that should work. It works for me.

```
int main(){
   char buf[128] = "(10)foo",
        reg[4]; 
   int a;
   int n = sscanf(buf, "(%d) %s", &a, reg);
   if ( n != 2 )
   {
      printf("Problem in sscanf\n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("a value = %d\nReg value = %s\n", a, reg);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change your sscanf line this way:

```
sscanf(buf, "(%d)%s",&a, reg);
```

Please note: you have to pass the pointer of your integer to sscanf()...

Comment: I appreciate the brevity. Thank you!